# Expression issue in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a string like this format. In my case I need to extract only the characters from string case

```
1)12AB
2)SD12
3)1WE4
```

output

```
1)AB
2)SD
3)WE
```

I need to extract only the characters. I am using this expression in the derived column in SSIS package

```
SUBSTRING(MediaIDCode,1,2)
```

but this expression works for only this condition

```
1)12AB
```

I need to get an expression that works for all the conditions above. I have tried using `REPLACE ( '' , '1', '')` but it becomes a big expression.

Comment: Could you have a code of `1W4E`? Are codes always 4 characters in total? Is `1)` etc actually part of the input row or is it just to indicate row numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The SUBSTRING function code you've posted will extract characters from a string without considering their content.

Have a look at using Regular Expressions to filter out unwanted characters:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/07/04/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-The-script-component-and-regular-expressions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a synchronous script transformation to filter characters this way:

```
    Dim NewMediaIDCode As String = ""

    For Each c As Char In Row.MediaIDCode
        If Not Char.IsDigit(c) Then
            NewMediaIDCode += c
        End If
    Next

    Row.MediaIDCode = NewMediaIDCode
```

I've used the IsDigit method here, but there's plenty of other methods to choose from.